# Compare two different classes based on their values

Tags: django, python-3.x, compare

I'm trying to compare two variables based on their actual values but it's just not working and I think it's because they are from different classes.
Here's an example :

```
models = Model_info.objects.all()
m = 'X-POWER 3'
for model in models:
    if m == model:
        check = 'accepted'
        print(check)
        break
    else:
        check = 'rejected'
        print(check)
print(f'final resulte is {check}')
```

So Knowing that the **value** of variable `m` does exist in the queryset `models` and :

```
type(m) = < class 'str' >

type(model) = < class 'application.models.Model_info' >
```

is there any method to compare the value of two variables no matter what class they belong to.

Comment: u need to check `m == model.field_name` with which u need to check the value wth

Comment: yes that's exactly what i want to do

Comment: it's simple as trying to compare A = 3 with B = "3", they have the same value but type(A) = < class 'int' > and type(B) = < class 'str' > so for that particular reason the code wont consider that A = B.

Comment: then typecast it. do `int(m) == model.field`

Comment: I hope you need to check id (or any different field), instead of `__str__/__repr__` representation.

Comment: @Exprator i really appreciate it your suggestion was very helpful and efficient thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make a comparison with a queryset, you need to do this with a field name of your choosing.
Here's an example:
Assuming `ModelInfo` had a field like `name`, all you have to do is
compare the string `m` with the model instance's field(assuming the field `name` is also a string), i.e:

```
m = 'X-POWER 3'
for model in models:
    if m == model.name:
        check = 'accepted'
    ... # continuation of your code
```